# why won't my array print correctly (bubble sort)

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

This program is supposed to print out the most popular ramen flavors based on the highest amount of bowls bought to lowest .

However If i randomly input amount of bowls sold as the following

(1 sold -for first flavor in the array)

( 2 sold - for second flavor in the array)

(3 sold- for third flavor in the array)

(4 sold-for fourth flavor in the array )

output

chicken       4

__           3

__           2

__           1

but if I assign the amount sold in descending order the program works

I would really appreciate your feedback

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main ()
{
    string flavor[]={"fish","lamp","steak" ,"chicken"}   ;
    int scoops[100]={};
    int sum=0;
    int x=0;

    for(x=0;x<4;x++)
    {
        cout <<"enter amount of bowls for the following ramen flavor :"<<flavor[x] <<endl;
        cin>>scoops[x];
        sum=scoops[x]+sum;
    }

    cout <<"total number of bowls is "<<sum<<endl;
    cout <<"list of the most popular flavors to least popular flavors "<<endl;//bubble sort


    int i=0,j=0,temp,char tempf;

    if(scoops[j]<scoops[j+1])
    {
        temp=scoops[j];
        scoops[j]=scoops[j+1];
        flavor[j]=flavor[j+1];
        scoops[j+1]=temp;
        flavor[j+1]=tempf;
    }



for (int a=0;a<4;a++)
{
    cout <<flavor[a] <<"\t"<<scoops[a]<<endl;
}
}
```

Comment: Bubble sort requires a loop. There's no loop in your code, just an if statement.

Comment: Use `std::swap(scoops[j], scoops[j+1]); std::swap(flavor[j], flavor[j+1]);` for swapping. Your current swapping is buggy since you don't save the flavor before assigning `flavor[j]`.

Comment: Your program doesn't compile as is (for example, you are trying to assing `char tempf` to `std::string` variable). Please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should iterate around the scoops[] array, check it the value and use the swap() function's that STL::algorithm provide us.

```
int length = sizeof(flavor)/sizeof(flavor[0]);
for (int i = 0; i < length-1; ++i)
{
     for (int j = i+1; j < length; ++j)
     {    
         if (scoops[i] > scoops[j])
         {
             swap(flavor[i], flavor[j]);    
         } 
     }
 }
```

Comment: Your implementation will keep looping even if the array is already sorted.

Comment: Oh right, all depends on the user's input. Your code looks cool, but in uncertain scoops length a linear burble sort algorithm implementation could be more subtle.

Comment: Your approach is not really a problem if you're dealing with very short arrays, but array of thousand elements will always equal million iterations. I will up vote  for the conciseness of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement bubble sort in your scenario like so

```
  int i = 0;
  bool is_sorted = true;
  int number_of_scoop_records = 4;

  // We keep looping over the array until all the elements are sorted
  while(true) {

    if(i >= (number_of_scoop_records-1)) {
      // All elements sorted, nothing to do anymore
      if(is_sorted)
        break;

      // Lets go around again
      i = 0;
      is_sorted = true;
      continue;
    }

    // Unsorted elements found
    if(scoops[i+1] < scoops[i]) {
      is_sorted = false;
      std::swap(scoops[i+1], scoops[i]);
    }
    i++;
  }
```